# The `zones.rfc1918` file for Bind9 and other 'good practice' for the Ubuntu 18.04 era?

Tags: bind, ubuntu-18.04

I am setting up Bind9 on Ubuntu 18.04 and found this SF article for Ubuntu 10.04: [What is the point of the zones.rfc1918 file for Bind9?](https://serverfault.com/questions/306104/what-is-the-point-of-the-zones-rfc1918-file-for-bind9), with a comment citing documentation from [Penn State in 1996](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt).

The question is still open after 8 years, has only one and popular answer: including `zones.rfc1918`'s information is "generally considered a good practice".

There are many other search results, but not addressing "good practice" for 18.04. Being in web 2.0 and approaching the Google world of https, I think some statement on whether arpa-related stuff is affected or unchanged is important.

Should I still "include" `zones.rfc1918` in my `named.conf.local` file for Ubuntu 18.04 (maybe other Linux contemporaries), y/n, etc? And, are there any other Bind9 settings similar to this that may have changed since that post that are recommended for me to change from the bind9 install defaults, y/n what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To address the clearly stated question, the `zones.rfc1918` file is pointless these days.

Not because the purpose (terminating queries to non-public zones locally instead of flooding the internet with useless queries if you are running a server with recursion enabled) is no longer relevant, but because [BIND already has the same kind of functionality built in and enabled by default](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.11/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#empty) without having to add zones in the configuration file to achieve this.

Comment: Current best practice: [RFC 6303](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6303.txt)

Comment: I'm in favor of adding the last paragraph of Håkan's  answer back but I don't just want to "unedit" Jesse's edit without asking the opinion of other forum members first.